# Gridview RowCommand event is fired when I do sorting in gridview

Tags: asp.net, rowcommand, gridview-sorting

I am trapped in some abnormal problem. When I do sorting in gridview, it fires RowCommand event for that grid instead of sorting event. Below is the HTML code for my grid view.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDefects" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"    OnPageIndexChanging="grdDefects_PageIndexChanging"
                OnSorting="grdDefects_Sorting" OnRowCommand="grdDefects_RowCommand"  AllowSorting="true">
                <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" FirstPageText="First"  LastPageText="Last"
                    NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Prev" />
                <Columns>
                    <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="ReasonID" Visible="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblReasonID" runat="server" Text='<%#  Bind("ReasonID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DefectId" HeaderText="Id" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DefectName" HeaderText="Defect"  sortExpression="DefectName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department Name" sortExpression="Department" />

                   <%-- <asp:ButtonField ControlStyle-CssClass="btns" ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Update"
                        Text="Edit" >
<ControlStyle CssClass="btns"></ControlStyle>
                    </asp:ButtonField>--%>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="editBtn" runat="server" Text="EDIT"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DefectId") %>' CssClass="btns"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

//Here is the code to handle those events.

```
protected void grdDefects_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (ViewState["sortMode"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["sortMode"] = strSORT_DESC;
        }
        else if(ViewState["sortMode"]!=null)
        {
            if (ViewState["sortMode"].ToString().Equals("strSORT_ASC"))
                ViewState["sortMode"] = strSORT_DESC;
            else
                ViewState["sortMode"] = strSORT_ASC;
        }
        //string strSortExpression = e.SortExpression;
        ViewState["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
        sort();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }  
}

protected void grdDefects_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        Response.Redirect("AddDefect.aspx?Id=" + Id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

How to solve this problem???

Comment: please post your code where you have handled the row_command and sorting events

Comment: @Pavitar. I have updated my question. You can see the code now.

Comment: Try debugging ,set a break point at statement...at `if(e.CommandName == "Update")` in the grdDefects_RowCommand event,as in your case and check if that is the one getting fired.Do you have any other Command Fields?

Comment: Sorting and Paging are bubbled up and go thru the Rowcommand. That is normal. What you are doing wrong is not wrapping your code in an if block that checks for your specific command name. if(e.RowCommand == "redirect"){ ... }

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Did you try checking commandName in  grdDefects_RowCommand

RowCommand events will fire whenever you click any button in GridView, whether its in header or in normal row. Just prevent your code from execution if its sorting event.

move the code from RowCommand event into this block

```
If (e.CommandName !="Sort")
{
}
```

Comment: No I have not checked but as I have handled sorting event of grid view, it must be fired when I do sorting. Its working perfectly in other pages.

Comment: @Needo please add a close the double quotes after `if(e.CommandName != "Sort")` If he does this, he will not know why the grdDefects_RowCommand is getting called , and which one CommandName is called.Because as it is, his sorting does not work.So this will take him no where